# Why does the order of imported repositories in build.gradle make or break the project?

Tags: android, google-api, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, jcenter

Please explain why the first code gives me syncing errors while the second doesn't.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

> Failed to resolve: play-services-base
>   Open File
>
> Failed to resolve: play-services-tasks
>   Open File

Changing the repository order syncs just fine:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Can someone give me a reason or educated guess why this occurs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This doc might be of use for you:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

Right down the bottom it mentions:

> **Note**: The order of declaration determines how Gradle will check for dependencies at runtime. If Gradle finds a module descriptor in a
> particular repository, it will attempt to download all of the
> artifacts for that module from the same repository. You can learn more
> about the inner workings of [Gradle’s resolution mechanism](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:declaring_multiple_repositories).

Comment: Your response was very helpful as was @commonsware's: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46145846/why-does-the-google-maven-repository-exist-and-when-should-i-use-it