# Setup issue for Android project

Tags: android, maven, gradle, nexus

So I am working at a larger company with mainly java development. Curious as developers are I decided to look into som Android development on my company laptop. Firstly I tried creating a kotlin project using gradle as build tool. I had a lot of issues with certificate errors until I resolved it by putting in

```
     repositories {
    maven {
      url "http://mavenlokation.companydomain.net"
      allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }
  }
```

because we apparently use nexus as middle man to store and validate artifacts

Now I tried to create an Android project and using the same resolution as above, but that does not seem to work...

I get

Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0.
Searched in the following locations:

- http://mavenlokation.companydomain.net/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.0.0/gradle-7.0.0.pom
  If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
  Required by:
  project :
  Add google Maven repository and sync project
  Open File

Any ideas...?

Comment: It's probably best to contact someone who is more knowledgeable in your company on resolving this issue, or try seeing how other colleagues are setting up the Maven `repositories` for Gradle.

Comment: You need to find out what version of the build tools is on your companies nexus and declare that version - or upload the version you want (7.0.0) to the companies nexus.

Comment: You need to add [the Google Maven repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46145846/208273).